# How can I filter by a polymorphic attribute for an attribute only existing in one class?

Tags: django, django-orm, django-filter, django-polymorphic

I'm uncertain how to phrase this question better, so please let me show an example:

I use Django-polymorphic and have this structure:

```py
from polymorphic.models import PolymorphicModel
from django.db import models


class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.OneToOneField(
        "Author",
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )

class Author(PolymorphicModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)

class AnonymousAuthor(Author):
    known_as = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
```

I want to filter for all books by the anonymous author known as `"foobar"`.

I tried:

> Book.objects.filter(author__known_as="foobar").all()

but I get:

> Cannot resolve keyword 'known_as' into field. Choices are: name.

I can filter for books by anonymous authors like this:

> aa_ctype = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(AnonymousAuthor)
> Book.objects.filter(author__polymorphic_ctype=aa_ctype)

But even with that I cannot filter for books with that name.

How can I filter for all Books by the anonymous author `"foobar"?

It is necessary to do the filtering with Django ORM. In my actual example I need to do this for django-filters.

Answer (score 0):

I found it:

```py
Book.objects.filter(author__anonymousauthor__known_as="foobar").all()
```

So the pattern is:

```
{attribute}__{classname in lowercase}__{attribute}
```

I just tried it and it works like a charm :-)

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is that your PolymorphicModel is not `Book` but `Author`.

So:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    .....

class Author(PolymorphicModel):
    ....

class AnonymousAuthor(Author):
    ....
```

Comment: That was just a mistake when I simplified my actual problem. I fixed the question. Your answer does not help with the actual question.